# Spring Data Rest is organizing query results by sub-type when when using super-type REST endpoints

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest

Given an Spring Data Rest project, suppose that I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "blabla")
public abstract class Type1 {
     //class code
}

@Entity
public class Type2 extends Type1 {
     //class code
}
```

As you may noticed I'm using table inheritance to model my Java inheritance hierarchy. Then I have the following repositories (from Spring Data Rest):

```
public interface Type1Repository extends JpaRepository<Type1, Long> {

}
```

And:

```
public interface Type2Repository extends JpaRepository<Type2, Long> {

}
```

Now assume that I have some Type2 rows in the database. Whenever I hit the whole Type1 REST collection (which ends up calling the findAll method from my Type1Repository inherited from JpaRepository) like this:

```
http://{{IP}}:{{PORT}}/type1
```

I receive a data structure that looks something like this:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "type2": [
        ...
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    ...
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 206,
    "totalPages": 11,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

So here is the thing... My entities are retrieved organized by sub-types. So the whole page of Type2 entities will be inside the _embedded.type2 array. This is cool on certain situations but in my particular case I just want them to be retrieved as Type1 entities because I've hit the Type1 collection. To be more clear what I want is the following data structure:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "type1": [
        ...
    ]
  }, ...
```

How can I configure my Data Rest repository in order to work that way?

**NOTE:**
I'm having this issues even when defining my own explicit query methods like this:

```
public interface Type1Repository extends JpaRepository<Type1, Long> {
    @Query(...)
    public Page<Type1> someQuery(Pageable pageable);
}
```

**NOTE:**
I'm using Spring boot 1.3.2.RELEASE

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. It comes from the Type2 repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "type1")
public interface Type2Repository extends JpaRepository<Type2, Long> {

}
```